# Can't add "ctrl+alt+;" keymap on Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm trying to add a keymap `["ctrl+alt+a", "ctrl+alt+;"]` on my Sublime Text 2, but it seens that `;` doesn't work at all on keymaps.

The complete line of the keymap is bellow, and the full list of my user keymaps and settings is at [a gist of mine](https://gist.github.com/SamuraiDio/1c55ab03585787486882).

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+a", "ctrl+alt+;"], "command": "align_tab", "args" : {"user_input" : "\\:/l0r1f"} },
```

Is there some way to make `;` work on keymaps?

Comment: What OS are you using? I tried setting that key combo for new window on OSX and it worked for me.

Comment: What is the character showing up when you press Ctrl + Alt + ;? Try to use it alone instead of Ctrl + Alt + ;

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. Not character shows up. Using just `;` works.

Comment: In the ST console enter `sublime.log_input(True)` and `sublime.log_commands(True)`. The first command should show you what keys are being received by ST. The second will ensure nothing is being run. Have you tried binding the command to another key combination you know works just to make sure it is working correctly. Perhaps there is something wrong in the arguments, rather than with the keybinding.

Comment: Logging input shows `ctrl+;` or `alt+;` as `ctrl+/` and `alt+/`, respectively, and `/` does not work with `ctrl` or `alt` at all.

Comment: ...Maybe a problem to recognize the keyboard layout (Brazilian portuguese, ABNT 2).

Comment: Found a post on Sublime forum about the problema. Seens to be a bug on the Editor. Still not fixed. [Key Bindings don't work](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7288&p=49843)